# lmx file format in android

Tags: android

Is Android capable of recognizing the lmx file format for a landmark when it receives one  by e-mail ? Can it react to this by opening google maps , or other application ?

Answer (score 2):

The *.lmx file format is not supported for Google Maps like that. But basically its just another XML Namespace. So you could build your own App or maybe there is already one in the market, which can convert it on-the-fly.
The format specification is located here: http://sw.nokia.com/id/9001c8de-c19e-41a0-87d3-5be4297e4d4c/S60_Platform_Landmarks_Exchange_Specification_v1_0_en.pdf

Comment: Suppose I receive such file on my mail application of choice. Can I detect than I received a lmx and then do my own custom thing ?

Comment: If you would build an app for that, sure. It should be something with the Intent-Filters but I am not that sure how it goes.
Probably with the ACTION_XXXXX methods which are for sending data aswell. E.x. when you build an app, which includes itself into the "Share"-List, when you've taken a picture, it needs an Intent Filter with ACTION_SEND. Android will search through every app, to get those filters. And I bet there is one for handleing special file extensions aswell.

Comment: Thanks , that throwed some light !